# Promises and Syncing the View and Model in Angular

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-promise, angular-services

My basic question is what is the best practice for keeping the model and the view in synch in angular, especially when it is a single object.  I have been trying to play around with promises, but cant seem to get anything to work. The thing I am trying to do is increment the upvotes on post, a popular example.

ok heres the code: function I am working on is the incrementUpvotes function.

Factory:

```
(function() {
  ngNewsApp.factory('posts', posts);

  posts.$inject = ['$http', '$q'];

  function posts($http, $q) {
    var service = {
      postList: [],
      getPosts: function() {
        return $http.get('/posts').success(function(data) {
          angular.copy(data, service.postList);
        });
      },
      savePost: function(post) {
        return $http.post('/posts', post).success(function(data) {
          service.postList.push(data);
        });
      },
      getPost: function(id) {
        return $http.post('/posts/' + id).success(function(result) {
          return result.data;
        });
      },
      upvote: function(post) {
        return $http.put('/posts/' + post._id + '/upvote');
      }
    };

    return service;
  }

})();
```

Controller:

```
ngNewsApp
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'posts', function ($scope, posts) {
    $scope.posts = posts.postList;

    $scope.addPost = function() {
      if(!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') {
        return;
      }

      posts.savePost({
        title: $scope.title,
        link: $scope.link
      });

      $scope.title = '';
      $scope.link = '';
    };

    $scope.incrementUpvotes = function(post) {
      posts.upvote(post).success(function(post) {
        post.upvotes++;
      });
    };
  }]);
```

Comment: "but cant seem to get anything to work. " please elaborate on that

Comment: well for one, posts.upvote(post) returns a promise. but I can't seem to chain another on to it.  When I call .success on it an just put a console.log in it. it doesn't fire.

Comment: you should always use `then` instead of `success`